# RecyclerView item dragging while keeping background visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView drag & drop works perfectly by attaching `ItemTouchHelper` to `RecyclerView`. Like below:

```
    abstract class RecyclerViewDragDetector : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN or ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, 0) {

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
    }

    override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)

        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
            viewHolder?.itemView?.alpha = 0.5f
        }
    }

    override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)

        viewHolder.itemView.alpha = 1.0f
    }
}
```

I am able to drag & drop items using above code, but the problem is while dragging an item, that position remains blank just like empty. My requirement is to keep a background place holder visible while dragging an item.
I want something like below image.
[image]

Any suggestion is really really appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps? https://github.com/NehaKushwah993/DragDropAnimation

Comment: @NehaK Thanks my friend for this reference. I will try to customize it to fit my requirement.